# Missing 2 required positional arguments - Classmethod Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class-method

Sorry, I'm struggling at this for quite some time. I'm trying to use function totalPayments which uses the monthlyPayment class function with parameters pass through in the initialisation phase. I'm getting an error missing 2 required positional arguments

```
class Loan(object):
   def __init__(self, asset, face, rate , term):
       self._asset = asset
       self._face = face
       self._rate = rate
       self._term = term

   @classmethod
   def monthlyPayment(cls,face,rate,term,period=None):
       return ((rate*face*((1+rate)**term)))/(((1+rate)**term)-1)

   def totalPayments(self):
       return (self.monthlyPayment(self) * self._term) 

l = Loan(None,1000,0.025,10)
print(l.totalPayments()) # gets an error missing 2 required positional arguments
```

edit:
Thank you very much for the hekp and I should be amending my def monthlyPayment function to take in the arguments

Comment: You are only passing one parameter to a function that you defined to require three. Please clarify in how far the error is unexpected and/or unclear to you.

Comment: Note that it is entirely unclear why you defined the method as a classmethod in the first place - it does not use the class, it takes all fields of a class instance, and you pass it a class instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `monthlyPayment` from the instance (`self`), and you're not providing arguments for `face`, `rate`, and `term`.

It also shouldn't be a classmethod, since you use attributes of the instance:

```
class Loan(object):
   def __init__(self, asset, face, rate , term):
       self._asset = asset
       self._face = face
       self._rate = rate
       self._term = term

   def monthlyPayment(self, period=None):
       return ((self._rate*self._face*((1+self._rate)**self._term)))/(((1+self._rate)**self._term)-1)

   def totalPayments(self):
       return (self.monthlyPayment() * self._term)
```

Answer (score 1):

The stack error you get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/cd00119621/PycharmProjects/ideas/stackoverflow.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(l.totalPayments())
  File "C:/Users/cd00119621/PycharmProjects/ideas/stackoverflow.py", line 13, in totalPayments
    return (self.monthlyPayment(self) * self._term)
TypeError: monthlyPayment() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'rate' and 'term'
```

The clue here is that its the `monthlyPayment()` method thats giving the error missing 2 args. this method expects 3 args passed to it (excluding self) and the 4th is optional.

`def monthlyPayment(cls,face,rate,term,period=None):`

but when you call this from your `totalPayments` method you only pass one argument which is self.

`return (self.monthlyPayment(self) * self._term)`

you dont need to pass self, it will be passed automatically, so you need to pass the other 3 expected params `face,rate,term`